# Atk not supported sabre

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I am using the sabre soap api for getReservationRQ.But I am getting this error as ATK not supported. Note I am using the sessionless token for the request .The request and response format are as follows.

```
<GetReservationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18" Version="1.18.0">
<Locator>XXXXXX</Locator>
<RequestType>Trip</RequestType>
<ReturnOptions>
    <ViewName>Default</ViewName>
    <ResponseFormat>STL</ResponseFormat>
</ReturnOptions>
```

The error is as follows

```
<stl18:GetReservationRS xmlns:stl18="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18" xmlns:ns6="http://services.sabre.com/res/orr/v0" xmlns:raw="http://tds.sabre.com/itinerary" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrconn/ReaccSearch" xmlns:or112="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_12">
<stl18:Errors>
    <stl18:Error>
        <stl18:Code>500307</stl18:Code>
        <stl18:Message>ATK not supported</stl18:Message>
        <stl18:Severity>MODERATE</stl18:Severity>
    </stl18:Error>
</stl18:Errors>
```

Comment: How you have solved this error ? Let me know thanks.

Comment: It was very old . I suggest you consult with sabre support they provide great support

Comment: Yes I had contacted them, and they provide me to first create a session request then use the service, actually I was using token which was taken from rest api, because in doc it's clearly mentioned that we can use rest api token in soap requests, but first a session must be created in order to get response from soap endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using Stateless? That should be used with sessionless tokens.

Comment: Yes but when I try stateless it gives me Pnr is restriced